# WPF "Cannot locate resource 'blah blah"

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have some images in my resources, the build action is resource and copy action is copy if newer. Anyhow, the images work fine in both designer and runtime except for when I use the control they are a part of inside another control, then it shows me this box with an exclamation mark and underlines the piece of code. For instance

```
<local:uiTimeRuler Grid.Column="1"/> <-"Cannot locate resource 'resources/icocelestialruler.png'"
```

while inside uiTimeRuler.xaml i have

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="bRuler" UriSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/icoCelestialRuler.png"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and it works fine there. Why is this happening?

Comment: Try to specify assembly as well :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly

Comment: This does not work because your application will try to find your image inside Resources folder of your Application instead of Resources folder of your UserControl. So, try to specify assembly as @Aybe mentioned in his comment.